# Thinking Sphinx index rebuild error on windows xp: searchd is already running

Tags: windows-xp, sphinxsearch, indexing-service

I have Sphinx installed on windows xp system. A I use Thinking Sphinx plug-in within my rails application.

I can't rebuild index with Thinking Sphinx rake task after application server starting up even if I stop it:

```
Stopped search daemon (pid 4492).
... bla bla bla ...
total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 1.3 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 9 writes, 0.000 sec, 1.2 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
WARNING: could not open pipe (GetLastError()=2)
rake aborted!
searchd is already running.
```

If I reload system, I can rebuild index. What do you think about?

Answer (score 2):

Everything became o'k after I had reinstalled sphinx service with this command:

```
C:\worktools\sphinx\bin>searchd.exe --install --config "C:\worktools\sphinx\sphinx.conf"
```

**NB**: config path should be in quotes. And I didn't use **--servicename** option as I did it during my first installation.